# Get combox to show ar listed, not sorted

Tags: autohotkey

Using .AHK file, how can I get the combobox drop down to show in the order as listed in the code, not as a sorted list?

```
WS.AddText("T_Depth", TX, 30, TW, TH, "Depth",,,,,, "Right")
WS.AddCombobox("C_Depth", EX, EY, EW,, "9 1/2""|11 7/8""|14""|16""|18""",,,, "I" Row)
```

It always comes out as sorted.

[image]

Comment: Can you show more code? eg. code for AddComboBox ?

Comment: Your right, I inherit this and found a code file that loads all the tabs.